# jQuery messes up line breaks

Tags: jquery, replace, textarea

I've got an if else statement. Switching between a text in `<p>` tag and the same text in an editable `<textarea>`

The problem is that:

1. you press the edit button and script converts p tag to textarea. Text is converted fine with line breaks.
2. You press save. Text is converted correctly back into a p tag again.
3. You try to press edit again... but this time, the linebreaks are ignored!?

   ```
   var curState = "Ret";

   if (curState == "Gem"){
           curState = "Ret";

           var p = btn.closest("div").find("textarea");

           var t = jQuery(this).closest("div").children("div").children('textarea').data();

           var ta = jQuery("<p/>", {
           "data": t
           });
           p.replaceWith(ta); 
   }else{
           curState = "Gem";

           var p = jQuery(this).closest("div").find("p");

           var t = p.data()

           var ta = jQuery("<textarea/>", {
           "class": "editTextarea",
           "data": t
           });
           p.replaceWith(ta);
   }
   ```

Comment: Don't use html method on a textarea.... set it's value with val(). Beyond that it appears you are replacing all the line breaks so it is expected it would be different second time. Please provide a **runnable** [mcve]. Click on `<>` in question editor to create a snippet that will run in this page

Comment: Hint: try storing original text that includes `\n` in `data()` of the `<p>` instead of relying on it's textContent

Comment: @charlietfl Sorry. It´s edited now. I tried with .data() as you can see in the updated question. But didn't make any difference

Comment: Please make this code **runnable** so we can see the issue ourselves. Just need enough basic html and include jQuery library in a *stack snippet* by clicking on `<>` in question editor

Comment: Use of `data()` is incorrect also. To **set** need a key and value, to **get** need same key. https://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: [How to create runnable stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/1175966)

Comment: @charlietfl I can´t get it to reproduce the same way. But this illustrates the problem http://jsfiddle.net/y5pn0qw4/18/  ...It is not a the p tag position thought. Is at the textarea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is take the html from `<p>` and insert it into another container then use `replaceWith()` on the `<br>` and pull that modified html out to use as value for the textarea

---

Simple working demo:

```js
// create temporary element to insert the `<p>` html into
var $content = $('<div>').append($('p').html())
 // replace <br> tags
 $content.find('br').replaceWith('\n')
// set value using modified html
$('textarea').val( $content.html() )
```

```css
p{border:2px solid #ccc; padding: 1em}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Line 1<br/><br><br/>Line 2
</p>
<textarea rows="10"></textarea>
```

Comment: Brilliant!! Thanks a lot!

Comment: The only thing is that it inserts like to ekstra line breaks?

Answer (score 0):

You have to retrieve the content of `p` element with `html()` instead of `data()`.

Once you have the content, replace `<br>` by `\n`:

```
var t = p.html()

var ta = jQuery("<textarea/>", {
    "class": "editTextarea"
});

ta.val(t.replace('<br>', '\n');
```

Comment: `ta.val(t.text())` should do same thing and won't run into issues for self closing `<br/>`. Also `replace()` without a `g` flag only replaces first instance

Comment: The problem with `text` is that is not taking in consideration when there is a double line break.